# How do I disable Cython?

Tags: python, linux, installation, lxml, cython

I'm trying to install lxml in python, but it seems that Cython is screwing up the installation (according to the install instructions).

I'm on a centos operating system, and I tried to yum remove cython, but apparently it can't find the package, even though it's there when I type whereis.

Is there a way to temporarily disable Cython? I can't find this information anywhere.

Edit: I tried the following:

```
[root@tawfik devin]# rpm -qa |grep cython
[root@tawfik devin]# whereis cython
cython: /usr/local/bin/cython
[root@tawfik devin]# rpm -e /usr/local/bin/cython
error: package /usr/local/bin/cython is not installed
```

Comment: use `rpm -qa |grep cython` you will find the package

Comment: How are you installing lxml? I would recommend using pyenv to create a python virtual environment - it makes it much easier to manage dependencies. See for instance [this blog post](http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2014/04/20/better-python-version-and-environment-management-with-pyenv/). I believe using yum to manage python dependencies is advised against for CentOS, because you should leave the OS version of python alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following command to find the package

```
rpm -qa |grep cython
```

Then if found then copy past your package name in this command to remove it.

```
rpm -e <package_name>
```

Comment: @Devinity let me know if it solved your query else I will check again.

Comment: Sorry looks like it's an utility not an package of the python.

Comment: Apparently I have the binary but it is not installed.